# Unable to hook up interceptor on classes/interfaces in asp.net core 3.1 application

Tags: autofac

Packages: Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection (6.0.0), Autofac.extras.DynamicProxy(4.5.0)

I am trying to prototype an interceptor for all of our service classes/interface serving the Web API controllers in our application, by following the ASP.NET Core 4.0 and the Interceptor documentation. The Interceptor is just a simple Log action using Serlog:

```
    public MethodCallInterceptor()
    {
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var text = invocation.Method.Name;
        Log.Logger.Debug($"Interceptor (Method): {text}");

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
```

Our main application sets up Autofac with ComApiApplication as the "Startup" class:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<ComsApiApplication>());
    }
```

In ComsApiApplication, I register most of ASP.NET MVC services in ConfigureServices (e.g. Authentication, Authorization etc). Then, I hook up the Interceptor for classes in a couple of our service assembles in its ConfigureContainer function:

```
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var assembly in Options.Assemblies)
        {
            // Add application services: IService => Service.
            var registrations = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains(".Services") && type.GetInterfaces().Any() && !type.IsAbstract)
                .Select(type => new
                {
                    Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(inf => inf.Name.Contains(type.Name)),
                    Implementation = type
                });

            foreach (var registration in registrations)
            {
               //builder.RegisterType(registration.Implementation).As(registration.Service).InstancePerDependency().EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(MethodCallInterceptor));
                    builder.RegisterType(registration.Implementation).As(registration.Service).EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InstancePerDependency().InterceptedBy(typeof(MethodCallInterceptor));
            }
            builder.Register(c => new MethodCallInterceptor());
        }
    }
```

However, when I run the application with requests leading to call the interface functions in those services (inheritance exists in our interfaces and service classes), I get the following exception and would be grateful for any help in identifying my issue:

Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details.
 ---> Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerationException: This is a DynamicProxy2 error: Target type for the proxy implements Castle.DynamicProxy.IProxyTargetAccessor which is a DynamicProxy infrastructure interface and you should never implement it yourself. Are you trying to proxy an existing proxy?
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.HandleExplicitlyPassedProxyTargetAccessor(ICollection`1 targetInterfaces, ICollection`1 additionalInterfaces)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GetTypeImplementerMapping(Type[] interfaces, Type proxyTargetType, IEnumerable`1& contributors, INamingScope namingScope)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GenerateType(String typeName, Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<GenerateCode>b__0(String n, INamingScope s)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.ObtainProxyType(CacheKey cacheKey, Func`3 factory)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GenerateCode(Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, Type targetType, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, Type targetType, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, Object target, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, Object target, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`3.<EnableInterfaceInterceptors>b__0(Object sender, ActivatingEventArgs`1 e)
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.RaiseActivating(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor: Information: Executing JsonResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 1):

The following is from Google Translate:
Coincidentally, I just solved this problem, but this is not the correct solution.
Just need to downgrade the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package to **5.0.1** to solve the problem.