# migration from asp.core 2.2 to 3.1. Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy

I am doing a migration and have encountered an exception. Autofac can resolve my service from an instance of a service provider, but cannot get it in my controller at the time of the request.

**Exception:** Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGe
  nerationException: This is a DynamicProxy2 error: Target type for the proxy implements Castle.DynamicProxy.IP
  roxyTargetAccessor which is a DynamicProxy infrastructure interface and you should never implement it yoursel
  f. Are you trying to proxy an existing proxy?

My AutoregistrableModule looks like that:

```
public class AutoregisterableModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly string _nameFilter;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nameFilter">Load will only search assemblies with names that contains filter</param>
    public AutoregisterableModule(string nameFilter)
    {
        _nameFilter = nameFilter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register's dependencies
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(_nameFilter));
        foreach (var library in dependencies)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
            assemblies.Add(assembly);
        }

        builder.Register(c => new LogInterceptor()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var isProd = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production";

        var containerBuilder = builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray())
            .Where(TypesToRegisterFilter)
            .PreserveExistingDefaults()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        if (!isProd)
        {
            containerBuilder.EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
        }

        base.Load(builder);
    }

    private static bool TypesToRegisterFilter(Type type)
    {
        return !type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SwaggerConfigureOptions)) && !typeof(BackgroundService).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}
```

If I remove that row all works well(except of my LoggerInterceptor :D)

```
containerBuilder.EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
```

My service looks like

```
 [Intercept(typeof(LogInterceptor))]
public class CategoriesService : ICategoriesService
{
     // some code here 
}
```

I tried to fix it by downgranding Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package from 6.0.0 to 5.0.1 as were suggested [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067943/unable-to-hook-up-interceptor-on-classes-interfaces-in-asp-net-core-3-1-applicat) but it didn't help.

You can find full Stacktrace there https://pastebin.com/YCAhLQv0 .

**So the question is how can I fix the exception and keep my interceptor working?**

Comment: You should include your dependency list here. Sounds like you may have something out of line but there's not enough info here.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by raising Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy package version from 4.5.0 to 5.0.0.
Hope it may help someone.